# Ionic 3. No provider for NavController

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, side-menu

My question is similar to the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049762/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-navcontroller)

But i'm not sure if its the same scenario for him, since the error goes away sometimes when I stop the app and restart using ionic serve. The error returns back again randomly. I have noticed that when I use debugger statement in the app.component.ts constructor I can bypass the error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my code

app.component.ts

```
export class MyApp {
    @ViewChild('content') nav: Nav;

    rootPage: any = HomePage;

    pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any }>;


    constructor(public platform: Platform,
    public statusBar: StatusBar,
    public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.initializeApp();

    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardPage },
    ];
    debugger
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
}
```

app.html

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>
<ion-nav #content swipeBackEnabled="false" [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

home.ts

```
export class HomePage {
  token: string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public menuCtrl: MenuController,
    public storage: Storage) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.storage.get('_token').then((token) => {
        this.token = token;
        if (this.token && this.token.length > 0) {
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage)
        } else {
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage)
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage)
      });
    }, 1000)
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
  }
  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
  }

}
```

login.ts

```
export class LoginPage {
  username: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public userProvider: UserProvider,
    public storage: Storage,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public menuCtrl: MenuController) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }

  login() {
    console.log("Logging in...", this.username, this.password);
    var credentials = { 'email': this.username, 'password': this.password };
    this.userProvider.login(credentials).then((validResponse: any) => {
      console.log('success', validResponse);
      var data = validResponse.data;
      this.storage.set('_token', data.token);
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage);
    }).catch((errorResponse: any) => {
      console.log('error', errorResponse);
      var title = '';
      var subTitle = '';
      title = "Oops!"
      if (errorResponse.status == 401) {
        subTitle = "Invalid Username/Password";
      } else {
        var errorObject = errorResponse.error;
        if (errorObject.errors) {
          for (let error of errorObject.errors) {
            subTitle += error + '. ';
          }
        } else {
          subTitle = errorResponse.message;
        }
      }
      this.presentAlert(title, subTitle);
    });
  }

  presentAlert(title, subTitle) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: title,
      subTitle: subTitle,
      buttons: ['Ok']
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
  }
  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
  }

}
```

login.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div class="login-holder">
    <ion-img class="logo" width="120" src="../../assets/imgs/logo.png"></ion-img>
    <br>
    <ion-img class="hero" width="250" src="../../assets/imgs/restaurant.png"></ion-img>
    <ion-input class="username" [(ngModel)]="username" type="text" placeholder="Phone or Email"></ion-input>
    <ion-input class="password" [(ngModel)]="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
    <button class="login" ion-button full (click)="login()">Login</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

My flow is like this, HomePage is a temporary screen before going to login page,
after a timeout I take to LoginPage or Dashboard Page, depending on if they already have a token in local storage. From Login page, I take the users to Dashboard Page.

Since I'm new to angular and ionic, I'm not even sure if I'm doing it right. I have looked into all the similar questions in stack overflow.

- Most of them got solutions by having passing App module in the constructor and retrieving navcontroller from the app. But that didnt work for me.
- Some suggested to check on the import path so I cross verified with docs & starter project it seems correct.
- Some suggested to remove passing nav controller in the constructor but if you check my code I havent passed in constructor in app.component.ts I have only passed in the page's constructors which is in the skeleton code generated by the ionic generate page command.

Thanks again for the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around for a while. I found the problem. I was missing **@IonicPage** decorator in my home.ts. It got resolved after adding it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Home.ts to:

```
export class HomePage {
  token: string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public menuCtrl: MenuController,
    public storage: Storage) {

  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
  }
  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.storage.get('_token').then((token) => {
        this.token = token;
        if (this.token && this.token.length > 0) {
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage)
        } else {
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage)
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage)
      });
    }, 1000)
  }

}
```

Comment: Have changed that. But the problem still persists.